# Getting a decorator with args to work with method: self does not exist

Tags: python, oop, decorator

When I try to decorate a method with arguments in the decorate it gives me a `self` is not defined. if instead I change assign `val` as a class variable and use `MyCls.val` it now gives me MyCls is not defined! How do I decorate my mehtod?

```
def dodecorate(VAL):
    def decorate(func):
        def wrapped(*args,**kwargs):
            res = func(*args,**kwargs)
            if res == VAL:
                res = "one"
            return res
        return wrapped
    return decorate


class MyCls(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.val = 1

    @dodecorate(VAL = self.val)
    def onefrom1(self, x):
        return x
```

**EDIT** The above was an abstraction I invented to represent the original. Here is the actual code.

```
def retry_on_invalid_schema(MAX_RETRIES):
    def retrier(func):
        def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
            tries = 0
            res = None
            while tries < MAX_TRIES:
                try:
                    res = func(*args, **kwargs)
                    assert res.has_key('by')
                    assert res.has_key('id')
                    break
                except AssertionError:
                    res = None
                    time.sleep(2**tries)
                    tries += 1
                    continue
            return res
        return wrapped
    return retrier



class Base(object):

    def __init__(self):

        self.MAX_RETRIES = 3

    @retry_on_invalid_schema(MAX_RETRIES = self.MAX_RETRIES)
    def _get_api_response(self, uri):
        return json.loads(self._get(uri))

    def _get(self, uri):
        return requests.get(uri).text
```

Comment: Can you show your `instances`?

Comment: @Yax I am getting the error before I get the chance to instantiate it.

Comment: Neither `self` nor `MyCls` exist when the decorator function is called, during class definition. What are you really trying to achieve, here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use an existing decorator function on an instance method, note that you can redefine instance methods in `__init__`, calling the decorator directly rather than using the `@` syntax:

```
class MyCls(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.val = 1
        self.onefrom1 = dodecorate(self.val)(self.onefrom1)

    def onefrom1(self, x):
        return x
```

In use:

```
>>> a = MyCls()
>>> for x in range(3):
    print a.onefrom1(x)


0
one
2
```

Comment: I actually abstracted the problem into a simpler one that I invented for this question. The actual decorator is a bit more complex and does retries of HTTP requests if the response isnt what's expected. It is used across other pieces of the script and I want to reuse it in my class method.

Comment: sorry about that. I will post the actual thing, then. Thought it would just distract people away from the core problem with extraneous details.

Comment: maybe mixin will be more suitable for this task?

Comment: @pad based on the update, I have removed the first part of my answer - I think what's left does what you want.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: `@pad` decides to use decorator to implement api request retreies, I just suggest to create mixin instead of decorator to solve this task

Comment: @dizpers I think the point is that the OP *already has* the decorator, so wants to use that rather than write duplicate code. However, if you think a mixin implementation would be better, *write a new answer*.

Comment: @jonrsharpe thanks, your method is correct and is perhaps the only way to do it within the syntactical constraints I put. I ended up using a class based decorator and set the arg manually.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to pass `val` to the decorator, you can just access it via the instance. `self` contains the current instance and is passed to the wrapped method in the decorator, so you can access that in the decorator as the first argument.

```
def decorate(func):
    def wrapped(instance, *args, **kwargs):
        res = func(instance, *args, **kwargs)
        if res == instance.val:
            res = "one"
        return res
    return wrapped


class MyCls(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.val = 1

    @decorate
    def onefrom1(self, x):
        return x

c = MyCls()
print c.onefrom1(1)
print c.onefrom1(2)
```

output

```
one
2
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need a decorator with arguments.